# Codeigniter image resize/Crop issue

Tags: image, codeigniter

I am trying to make some thing like the image, where Uploaded images height/width will be not an issue and the system will make the images like the image. Can anyone tel me how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Read this https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html

Comment: you can handle that with bootstraps `img-responsive` even